# Flutter pass data from one statefulwidget to state

Tags: flutter, state, statefulwidget

i have the code below, i would like to pass 'channelname' from [1] to [2]. how do i achieve that?

error that i am receiving
'The instance member 'channelname' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression'

```
class VideoCallScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static Route get route => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const VideoCallScreen(),
      );
  final String? channelname; // -- [1]
  const VideoCallScreen({Key? key, this.channelname}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoCallScreen> createState() => _VideoCallScreenState();
}

class _VideoCallScreenState extends State<VideoCallScreen> {
  bool _isMute = false;
  bool _isSwitchCamera = false;
  bool _isDisableCamera = false;

  final AgoraClient client = AgoraClient(
    agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
        appId: AgoraConfig.appId,
        channelName: channelname), // -- [2]
    enabledPermission: [Permission.camera, Permission.microphone],
  );

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAgora();
  }

  void initAgora() async {
    await client.initialize();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Initialize `client` in `initState` function.
- Use `late` keyword to declare `client`.
- Use `widget.channelname` to access the `channelname`.

  ```
  class _VideoCallScreenState extends State<VideoCallScreen> {
    bool _isMute = false;
    bool _isSwitchCamera = false;
    bool _isDisableCamera = false;

    late final AgoraClient client;

    void initState() {
      client = AgoraClient(
        agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
          appId: AgoraConfig.appId,
          channelName: widget.channelname,
        ),
        enabledPermission: [Permission.camera, Permission.microphone],
      );
    }
  ...
  ```

Comment: sorry, i just added in

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initAgora();
  }

  void initAgora() async {
    await client.initialize();
  }
```